# Query to find lost URLs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, url

Is there a way to get URL names from SharePoint database?  Users have created the SharePoint sites and moved on and no one knows how to access the sites/databases.

Answer (score 0):

what you mean no body knows or access the sites?

If you are talking about the site collections then you can check from central admin.

> Central admin> Application management > view all site collection.....
>   On this page from right drop down select the web application and now you will see all created site collections under this web app.

You can change the primary and secondary site collections admin in order to get access.

But if you are talking about the subsite then you know the site collection,

> from site settings > view all site content

at the bottom of page you will see all the subsites for that site collections.